# Private Google account at work

Tags: google, chrome, account-security

I have an old private tablet at work with my private Google account on it .It's connected to our WiFi, where i logged in with my personal working code. Never use it much as I just play some music on it.

Today I saw that my browsing and history from my computer back home came up in Chrome on the tablet.

My question is: can my job see what am browsing at home just because am logged in on the tablet? Or is this information encrypted from Google? Never use the tablet at work for browsing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should not do any personal stuff like browsing, gaming, social media networking etc. on the same machine/workstation/tablet that you use for work.

This practice has contributed to many corporate breaches, here is the latest example:
https://castbox.fm/episode/Job-seeker-exposes-banking-network-to-Lazurus-Group-%E2%80%94-Research-Saturday-id101971-id134807630?country=us

---

> Today I saw that my browsing and history from my computer back home came up in Chrome on the tablet.

That's because you're signed in on both devices with the same Google account and have the Sync turned on. You can turn the sync feature off on your tablet and put 2FA on your account .. or better if make a new Gmail account altogether for the tablet.

> Can my job see what am browsing at home just because am logged in on the tablet? Or is this information encrypted from Google?

Technically no, as long as you don't hand over the password or unless you are using a Gsuite account on the tablet, your company admin can remotely wipe the device, set certain policies and even reset your corporate email password to get access to the history. So generally, it is a good practice to turn your history/location/voice tracking off.

But you have to take into consideration another aspect: You agree to submit to the information security policy of your company if you use your personal device at work, so beware, even if it is your personal device, locked with the password that only you know, your employer can ask you to hand over the password in case of any cybersecurity incident where the investigation of your machines might be required.

Stay paranoid!

Answer (score 0):

> Can my job see what am browsing at home just because am logged in on the tablet?

The short answer is no, they probably can't. Why probably? It depends on how your tablet is secured (pin code / facial recognition etc.)

Assuming it has some form of protection and no one is able to guess your pin code (or what ever it is you use to protect your tablet), you should be alright.

I think the reason why this is happening is because "sync" in enabled in Google Chrome. This synchronizes the data (browser history, bookmarks, passwords etc.) of your choosing over all the devices you use and log in with your Google account.